# python how to make "for-iteration" stop at "len" using dunder methods

Tags: python, magic-methods

I have several Python classes I use for calling C-code, using `c-types`. The return struct looks something like the below example.

```
import ctypes

class MyCClass(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('n_values', ctypes.c_int),\
                ('values', ctypes.c_double * 5)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return """n_values : {0}, values : {1}""".format(self.n_values,\
                             self.values)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.n_values

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.values[key]
```

The `values` array is fixed size to ease the call to C (using a variable size array here is not an option). The "actual" length of the array is controlled by the `n_values` variable.

For instance if `values` is an array of three numbers, say `1`, `2` and `3`,`values=[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]` and `n_values=3`.

This is all fine. The problem is when i implement `__len__` and `__getitem__`.

I want to be able to write code like this

```
for value in my_class:
    #do something
```

But the iterator does not seem to "get" that the `values`-array is only `n_values` long. I.e. it does not seem to use `MyCClass.__len__` to halt the iteration. Instead it seems to iterate over the full length of `values`.

```
my_class = MyCClass()

my_class.n_values = 3
sample_values = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(3):
    my_class.values[i] = sample_values[i]

i = 0
for value in my_class:
    print(i)
    i += 1
0
1
2
3
4
```

I want

```
i = 0
for value in my_class:
    print(i)
    i += 1
0
1
2
```

I know I can code

```
for i in range(my_class):
    # do something with my_class[i]
```

but that is not what I want.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: define an `__iter__` method in MyCClass.

Comment: Yes, because the "old" getitem based iterator protocol simply keeps going until it encounters an `IndexError`. Just implement the iterator protocol using `__iter__` and a generator, or perhaps using a custom iterator class that implements `__iter__` (returning self) and `__next__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the old-school iterator types, the only way is to raise an `IndexError`:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if key >= len(self):
        raise IndexError
    return self.values[key]
```

For a cleaner solution, consider using the more modern iteration protocol, i.e. returning an *iterator* instance from an `__iter__` method defined on your *iterable*.  That's documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).